# How to Interpret datadump from WordPress website

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am working reverse engineering my WordPress website into Rails. I'm doing this to get a better working knowledge of Rails and adding features I can't seem to add on WordPress without creating my own custom plugin.

I decided to start with taking a datadump of my website by going to goDaddy and then going to StarField Technologies which is a portal to view my database. I was given a large sql file which was named with the ip address .sql similar to 198.XX.XXX.XX:XXXX.sql. In this file there was queries to create tables, add, and modify entries. I'm assuming everyone I've made until date.

Now what I'm trying to do is to take this data, use a GUI to see the tables I have, and the relationships between them. My ultimate goal is to replicate this information in my own database and use Rails API to add/remove/modify the table data.

Can you please suggest me a good GUI like phpMyAdmin to see the tables and the relationships in a birds eye view?

Comment: phpMyAdmin seems fine, it have a plugin for table relationships, in fact.
But you can use MySQL Workbench too for this, you will need a working copy of the Wordpress database.